# Finding the maximum of the values in a file

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have a file which contains several numbers, as follows.

```
21 12 33 35 21 12 33 44 52 63 14 12 23 34 11 12 13 53 1 12 43 33 44
```

How can I find the maximum of these values, which is `63`? I wanted to use `stats` but it seems this command does not exist on my machine and I don't want to install it. How can I approach using `perl`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aUtil) (part of the standard library since 5.8, otherwise available on CPAN):

```
perl -MList::Util=max -lane 'print max(@F)'
```

Comment: `List::Util` is standard library.

Comment: @Gnouc My knowledge about that is out of date, I've updated. Thanks for letting me know. :-)

Comment: Thank you all. Is `List::Util` available on all Linux machines?

Comment: @A2009 That would depend on what you mean by a "Linux machine". If you mean that it should be there on systems conforming to a recent version of the LSB, the answer is [yes](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Languages/LSB-Languages/perlversion.html).

Comment: @ChrisDown For my input.txt (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f4d748a8327f5c5c6a59), I make use of the script

`perl -MList::Util=max -lane 'print max(@F) input.txt` and try to locate the maximum. The terminal returns a maximum row by row. May I know if it is possible to return a single value from multiple lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Other answers are quite nice and Perl / awk is the way to go.

Just for fun, you can also use this (assuming GNU `grep`):

```
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]+' file | sort -rn | head -n 1
63
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -Eo '[0-9]+' file` prints all matches of positive decimal integer numbers in the file. Each match will be printed in a different line, as per the `-o` flag.
- `sort -rn` sorts the list numerically and in reverse, so that the first number is the biggest.
- `head -n 1` prints the first line.

By steps:

```
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]+' file
21
12
33
35
21
12
33
44
52
63
14
12
23
34
11
12
13
53
1
12
43
33
44
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]+' file | sort -rn 
63
53
52
44
44
43
35
34
33
33
33
23
21
21
14
13
12
12
12
12
12
11
1
```

Answer (score 9):

I am aware this is not perl:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i>maxval) maxval=$i;}; END { print maxval;}' file
```

Comment: Thank you. Is `awk` available in all Linux machines?

Comment: @A2009 Yes, `awk` is a POSIX tool (as usual: with a standardized body of the language and incompatible extensions by the different implementations).

Comment: A nice feature of this solution is that it runs in O(n) time whereas the solutions that do a sort require O(n * log(n)). +1

Comment: It refers to the way the running time increases as the size of the set increases (See [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)). So if you multiply the input size by 100, an O(n) operation will take 100 times as long, but an O(n * log(n)) operation will take *mumbles* times as long. My math is wrong, but it goes up more. So while for small inputs, you really can't say which would be faster, for large enough inputs, the O(n) solution will be faster.

Comment: @laindir Re: "What does [it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) mean? That the performance scales in a more predictable way when the size of the set increases? Or that it's always faster?" Your comment has inspired this [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/241052/132481). Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Another `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=max -anle 'print max(@F)' file 
63
```

This will work with file contains one line, if you have muliple line in file, and want to find the maximum value over all lines, try:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=max -alne '$tmp = max @F; $max = $tmp if $max < $tmp; END { print $max }'
```

Comment: The reader should not forget to add `file` at the end of the second code.

Comment: It's very useful to have the commands for all-on-one-line and each-on-its-own-line files. Good work.

Comment: +1. Alternative multi-line version.  `perl -MList::Util=max -lane 'push @F, $max if ($max); $max = max @F; END{ print $max }' file`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a faster Perl approach that does not require sorting:

```
$ echo '21 12 33 35 21 12 33 44 52 63 14 12 23 34 11 12 13 53 1 12 43 33 44' |
    perl -lane 'map{$m=$_ if $_>$m}@F; print $m'
```

or, as @Gnouc suggested in the comments:

```
$ echo '21 12 33 35 21 12 33 44 52 63 14 12 23 34 11 12 13 53 1 12 43 33 44' |
    perl -lane '$m<$_ and $m=$_ for @F; print $m'
```

Comment: Maybe `$m>$_ and $m=$_ for @F`. With this, we don't have to create another array for `map`.

Comment: @Gnouc no, that fails. You could do `foreach(@F){$m=$_ if $_>$m}` though.

Comment: Oh, my mistypo `$m<$_ and $m=$_ for @F`.

Comment: That assumes the input has only one line.

Answer (score 2):

This works in Ubuntu, but didn't on MacOS:

```
echo "21 12 33 35 21 12 33 44 52 63 14 12 23 34 11 12 13 53 1 12 43 33 44" | grep -oE "[0-9]*" | sort -nr | head -n 1
```

First grep for patterns matching a number (add ., if you have decimals), then sort numeric in reverse order and then pick the first result.

Comment: Try this instead: `echo "21 12 33 35 21 12 33 44 52 63 14 12 23 34 11 12 13 53 1 12 43 33 44" | tr " " "\n" | sort -nr | head -n 1`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to support different sorts of numbers (-2, 1E-20, inf, 0x2f, 0b0101, 0777...), not just positive decimal integer ones, you could do:

```
perl -lne '
  while (m{(?!<\w)(?:(0x[0-9a-f]+|
            0b[01]+|
            0[0-7]+)|
           [-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(e[-+]?\d+)?|
           infinity|inf)(?!\w)}xgi) {
    $v = defined($1) ? oct($1) : $&;
    $m = $& unless defined($m) && $m >= $v
  }
  END {print $m if defined $m}'
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for awk, grep, or perl.

```
{ 
    for n in 21 12 33 35 21 12 33 44 52 63 14 12 23 34 11 12 13 53 1 12 43 33 44
    do 
        echo $n
    done 
} | sort | tail -n1
```

Comment: Why not simply `tr ' ' '\n' < infile | sort -n | tail -n1` since according to the OP, the numbers are stored in a file? Even if they weren't, you could still use [`tr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) like [velox suggested](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130899/finding-the-maximum-of-the-values-in-a-file#comment209589_130914).

Comment: Good call.  For some reason I tend to ignore `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is not `perl`, but I like GNU `awk` for this

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'BEGIN{max=-inf};{max = $0>max? $0: max};END{print max}' file
63
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grep '[0-9]*' number.sh | sort -rn | head -1
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Also the OP asked for a Perl solution.